# Play sound through headphone jack while connected to TV

Tags: sound, dell, hdmi, headphones, audio-jack

How can I play sound through the headphone jack while my Dell Inspirion 5447 laptop (running 16.04) is connected to a TV through HDMI?

Comment: This might be silly, but can't you connect your headphones to TV?

Comment: Iam using an old panasonic home theater which has red white yellow port which i have the cable for for aux 3.5.And there is no aux in my tv. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Pulse Audio Settings and switch output to the headset

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66072/discussion-on-answer-by-ravery-play-sound-through-headphone-jack-while-connected).

Comment: If you have had an extended convo in chat, it should give you a notice below the "Add comment" box on the site (doesn't work on mobile).  Mods can force move things to chat rooms, but we have an automatic system to note threads that have lots of comments in a short period of time and probably should be moved to chat.

Comment: Guys, I'm actively in chat.  If you want to discuss whether something came up or not, feel free to ***[bother me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)*** so that we don't flood this area with unnecessary superfluous comments.  Thanks!